# String interpolation using named parameters in C#6

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

Given I have a Meta Data resource string stored in my Database that will return like this:

```
var pageTitle = "Shop the latest {category1} Designer {category2} {category3} at www.abc.com";
```

And I want to replace the `{placeholders}` with variable `values`;

```
var category1 = "womenswear";
var category2 = "dresses";
var category3 = "cocktail dresses";
```

I have tried, with no luck;

```
var newTitle = $"pageTitle, category1, category2, category3";
var newTitle = $(pageTitle, category1, category2, category3);
```

I know that I could use `string.Replace()` that has a performance overhead. Does anyone know how this can be done efficiently using the latest C# string interpolation?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

> I know that I could use string.Replace() that has a performance overhead

Of mere nanoseconds. You shouldn't optimize prematurely.

As said, the C# 6 string interpolation feature happens at compile-time. If you want to do this at runtime, you'll have to use string replacement.

I assume your strings are formatted like that for ease of editing and not having a fixed replacement order, so simply do this:

```
var input = "Shop the latest {category1} Designer {category2} {category3} at www.abc.com";
var category1 = "womenswear";
var category2 = "dresses";
var category3 = "cocktail dresses";

var result = input.Replace("{category1}", category1)
                  .Replace("{category2}", category2)
                  .Replace("{category3}", category3);
```

This will just work. You could also store your replacement values in a dictionary, and loop over the keys to replace the key with the value.

Comment: Nitpick: If `category1 == "{category2}"` this will deliver unexpected results :) But I admit: I use this all the time.

Comment: @usr absolutely, walking over the string and matching each `{replacement}` to a dictionary is a better approach, see dasblinkenlight's answer.

Comment: `input.Replace("{" + nameof(category1) + "}", category1)` would also work, right? This is a bit too "magic-string"' for my liking anyway.

Comment: @Zack yeah, but that would still be susceptible to copy-paste errors. A dictionary containing the keys and replacement values is the way to go, not local variables.

Comment: @usr you can deal with that easily with a regex: `Regex.Replace(input, @"\{(.+?)\}", m => valuesDict[m.Groups[1].Value])` (except you'd use something that doesn't throw if the key doesn't exist)

Comment: @LucasTrzesniewski right, but to continue nitpicking, your regex would match `{{x}` which surely is not intended. Also `{x{x}`.

Comment: @usr indeed, that was just to point out a mechanism which does not have the multipass replacement issue. If you want a better regex you can always come up with something else, like `\{(\w+)\}` or `\{([^{}\s]+)\}` or even `\{((?>(?<b>\{)|(?<-b>\})|(?>[^{}\s]+))+(?(b)(?!)))\}` if you fancy ;)

Answer (score 20):

You can't use string interpolation here. String interpolation is a compile-time rewrite method for `string.Format`, which is the solution you should use:

```
var newTitle = string.Format("{0}, {1}, {2}, {3}", pageTitle, category1, category2, category3);
```

Or `string.Join`:

```
var newTitle - string.Join(", ", new string[] { pageTitle, category1, category2, category3 });
```

Since you are loading from database, it might be just better in your case to keep using `string.Replace`.

Comment: I thine either of those would result in `Shop the latest {category1} Designer {category2} {category3} at www.abc.com, womenswear, dresses, cocktail dresses"`

Comment: @DStanley I was just going forward from the last sample given. The replace is the actual solution in the case of OP.

Comment: How about an extension method that internally uses `string.Format` but uses placeholders with the actual variable names instead of `{0}`, `{1}` etc, is this possible?

Comment: Possibly, but off the top of my head, how would the extension method know what the variables in the calling method are?

Comment: @DStanley they do come out as `Shop the latest {category1} Designer {category2} {category3} at www.abc.com, womenswear, dresses, cocktail dresses`.

Answer (score 11):

Although .NET does not offer a built-in capability for this, you can easily build a pretty good implementation with regex:

```
public static string Format(string formatWithNames, IDictionary<string,object> data) {
    int pos = 0;
    var args = new List<object>();
    var fmt = Regex.Replace(
        formatWithNames
    ,   @"(?<={)[^}]+(?=})"
    ,   new MatchEvaluator(m => {
            var res = (pos++).ToString();
            var tok = m.Groups[0].Value.Split(':');
            args.Add(data[tok[0]]);
            return tok.Length == 2 ? res+":"+tok[1] : res;
        })
    );
    return string.Format(fmt, args.ToArray());
}
```

The idea is to replace names with consecutive numbers (see `sb.Append(pos++)`), build an array of object parameters (see `args.Add(data[tok[0]])`), and pass the result to `string.Format` to use `string`'s formatting capabilities.

Now you can pass your resource to this `Format`, along with a dictionary of key-value pairs, and get a string formatted using .NET's built-in formatting capabilities:

```
var x = new Dictionary<string,object> {
    {"brown", 1}
,   {"jumps", 21}
,   {"lazy", 42}
};
Console.WriteLine("{0}", Format("Quick {brown} fox {jumps:C} over the {lazy:P} dog", x));
```

Note that there is no `$` in front of the string literal, so there's no C#'s built-in interpolation going on here.

This prints

```
Quick 1 fox $21.00 over the 4,200.00 % dog
```

The approach is based on the [idea by Scott Hanselman](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/CommentView.aspx?guid=fde45b51-9d12-46fd-b877-da6172fe1791), except formatting is done differently.

[Demo.](http://ideone.com/wiTkDF)

Comment: Is there some reason why you'd want to do this instead of a `Regex.Replace` with `MatchEvaluator`?

Comment: @Luaan I wanted to keep Scott's code, but MatchEvaluator is a lot cleaner. Take a look at the edit.

Answer (score 5):

If you don't want to use string replacement, then you either need to use the original formatting syntax:

```
var pageTitle = "Shop the latest {0} Designer {1} {2} at www.abc.com";

var category1 = "womenswear";
var category2 = "dresses";
var category3 = "cocktail dresses";

var newTitle = string.Format(pageTitle, category1, category2, category3);
```

or put the formatting string *after* the variables:

```
var category1 = "womenswear";
var category2 = "dresses";
var category3 = "cocktail dresses";

var newTitle = $"Shop the latest {0} Designer {0} {0} at www.abc.com";
```

The string interpolation is converted to a `string.Format` call at *compile time*, so there's no way to make the formatting string a variable at run-time.

Comment: I think your first example would be the way OP would have to do it if they are getting the format string from a store like a DB.

Answer (score 1):

Please checkout my libary thats solves this problem [TinyTools](https://github.com/wendellmva/tinytools) if you use it give me an upvote and if you like it leave a star on github.

```cs
    var person = new Person
    {
        FirstName = "John",
        LastName = "Smith"
    };
    var template = "Hello world, I'm {FirstName} {LastName}";

    var result = template.Interpolate(person);
    result.ShouldBe("Hello world, I'm John Smith");
```